# 'Failure running Jump to Method Definition' error: undefined method `current_line' for TextMate:Module

Tags: ruby, textmate

Update: I figured it out. Ctrl-F only works when the method I'm searching is NOT selected. The cursor only needs to be IN the method name.

I just upgraded to TextMate2.

When I select a method and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to go to its definition, I get:

```
> Failure running Jump to Method Definition
```

Here's the trace:

```
/Users/ilikepie/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Ruby on Rails.tmbundle/Support/lib/rails/text_mate.rb:54:in `method_missing': undefined method `current_line' for TextMate:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/ilikepie/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Ruby on Rails.tmbundle/Support/bin/jump_to_method_definition.rb:13:in `initialize'
    from /Users/ilikepie/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Ruby on Rails.tmbundle/Support/bin/jump_to_method_definition.rb:147:in `new'
    from /Users/ilikepie/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Ruby on Rails.tmbundle/Support/bin/jump_to_method_definition.rb:147
```

I'm also given an option to Edit Command". Here's the code for the "Jump to Method" Definition:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[[ -f "${TM_SUPPORT_PATH}/lib/bash_init.sh" ]] && . "${TM_SUPPORT_PATH}/lib/bash_init.sh"

RUBYLIB="$TM_BUNDLE_SUPPORT/lib:$RUBYLIB"
"${TM_RUBY:=ruby}" -- "${TM_BUNDLE_SUPPORT}/bin/jump_to_method_definition.rb"
```

Am I missing an environment variable?

Comment: Not a real solution, but I started digging into the source, printing out environment variables along the stack trace above, and that somehow fixed the problem.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is Ctrl-F only works when the method I'm searching is NOT selected. The cursor only needs to be IN the method name.

Comment: How is this a ruby question?

Comment: The Jump to Method Definition feature is a Ruby feature.

Comment: Instead of adding comments as you find out things, which makes it really difficult for others to figure out what you know, append them to your question. It isn't necessary to use "Edit:" or "Update" or such, instead put them into the question appropriately to make sense. (We can tell what was added when if necessary.)

Comment: Rather than add additional text to your question saying you fixed it, create an answer explaining what you did, then, when the system allows, select that answer as the correct one. By doing so you mark your question as having an answer, which removes it from the unanswered list, and will give you the points.

Comment: I didn't want to do that because I didn't feel it's a 'real' answer. But I suppose it can be argued that it is since it did fix the problem for me and apparently some other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Ctrl-F only works when the method I'm searching is NOT selected. The cursor only needs to be IN the method name.